# Design decision to migrate Silverlight application

Tags: angularjs, silverlight, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I have a silverlight application, it has pretty complex UI. In some forms I am using MVVM pattern. However there are many forms where code behind file has most of the form logic code (no view model).

Silverlight application is having both business and UI logic. There is a WCF service which SL application is directly calling. This WCF service is a data service (DB logic).

I want to migrate silverlight application into HTML5. I have following questions.

1. There are many links to migrate the SL application to HTML5 (even using MVVM pattern). Many suggests to use some JS framework library like AngularJS/Knockout. Can you please tell me which one works best for migration from SL?
2. Where would I put the business logic? Can I write my business logic using JS library? Also in case I write business logic using some library then won't it expose all my logic to client?
3. In case JS library is not the right thing to write the business logic then what other technology I should use? WebAPI or something else?

Atul Sureka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For Server Side Code Reusablity (MVVM) Code use AngularJS/KendoUI
    Use C# Object to JavaScript Object Convrsion
2. Server Side Logic we can Re-Use, Client Side Logic C# to Java Script
3. User Rest API's